# AWS lambda function throws error even after providing all modules

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pypandoc

I want to convert .docx file to .txt and If .docx has tables I want to maintain them in good way in .txt file , so I am using pypandoc for this purpose .
In my local this is working like charm.
When I zip it with all dependencies and put it in s3 to run via aws lambda it fails with below error:

> 

No pandoc was found: either install pandoc and add it
to your PATH or or call pypandoc.download_pandoc(...) or
install pypandoc wheels with included pandoc

> 

My code is like :

```
import boto3
import logging
import pypandoc
local_file_docx =  '/tmp/'+prefix+'german-de.docx'
local_file_txt =  '/tmp/'+prefix+'german-de.txt'
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(pypandoc.convert_file(local_file_docx, "plain+simple_tables", format="docx", extra_args= 
    (), encoding='utf-8', outputfile=local_file_txt))
```

Any help . Aprreciated in advance

Comment: My local system is windows laptop where this runs

Comment: For this task important first of all not Lambda Python code but how you try to deploy it to AWS. Here is an AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Comment: Yes in same way I have deployed it to AWS after zipping all dependencies and putting it in s3 .